# Passing variables through navigateURL to open iFrame as3

Tags: actionscript-3, iframe, paypal, navigateurl

By using NavigateURL I can easily pass variables as below through Flash to paypal, this works no problem and can include all the data required.

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");
var reqVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
reqVars.cmd = "_xclick-subscriptions";
reqVars.business = "BUSINESS CODE";
reqVars.lc = "GR";
reqVars.item_name = "Product Name";
reqVars.item_number = "Product Number 0001";
reqVars.no_note = "1";
reqVars.no_shipping = "2";
reqVars.src = "1";
reqVars.a3 = "15.00";
reqVars.p3 = "1";
reqVars.t3 = "Y";
reqVars.currency_code = "EUR";

//and so on
req.data = reqVars;
req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
navigateToURL(req);
```

By using callIframe as shown below I can easily open an iFrame from Flash.

```
calliFrame("http://www.webAddress.com/" +"?iframe=true&width=800&height=550", "Page Title", "Page Description");

function calliFrame(url:String, title:String, desc:String):void{
    if (ExternalInterface.available) {
        trace("calling prettyPhoto");
        try {
            ExternalInterface.call('$.prettyPhoto.open', url, title, desc);
        } catch (event:Error) {
            trace("Error occurred!");
        }
    } else {
        trace("External Interface unavailable");
    }
}
```

Is it possible to pass the navigateURL variables through the calliFrame method? I've tried variations but not gotten to either transfer the data or show the page.

I hoped something like the example below would work but only get a blank page or list of the data shown in the iFrame:

```
calliFrame("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" +reqVars +"?iframe=true&width=800&height=550", "Page Title", "Page Description");
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter is the window name, so all you gotta do is pass the name of your iframe.

```
public function navigateToURL(request:URLRequest, window:String = null):void
```

docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL()

Comment: Thanks @bribeiro. Having spent a little time trying many options, I think it may be a security issue though as Paypal and Facebook now implement the same logic with iFrames. I'll try your recomendations anyway and can probably implement them elsewhere but I suspect opening paypal from my site in an iFrame is a non starter. . .Sadly.